# Min and Max on a SUM column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
Phrase    |  qty
phrase_1  |  4  
phrase_1  |  1
phrase_1  |  8
phrase_2  |  2
phrase_3  |  3
phrase_3  |  2
```

What I initially return is:

```
phrase_1 | 13
phrase_3 | 5
phrase_2 | 2
```

Using:

```
SELECT phrase, sum(qty) as total
FROM mytable
GROUP By phrase
ORDER BY total DESC
```

What I need, and can't figure out, is how to return the min and max with the results.

so I would get:

```
phrase, qty, min, max
phrase_1 | 13 | 2 | 13
phrase_3 | 5  | 2 | 13
phrase_2 | 2  | 2 | 13
```

Because I want to run a normalization on the resultset and return a new order based on values between 1 and 0.

Something like (this doesn't work):

```
SELECT phrase, sum(qty) as total, (total - min(total)/max(total) - min(total)) AS rank
FROM mytable
GROUP By phrase
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

The above statement is ultimiately what I'm looking to do and not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some subqueries you can achieve your goal, but pretty it will never get

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (
>   `Phrase` VARCHAR(8),
>   `qty` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO mytable
>   (`Phrase`, `qty`)
> VALUES
>   ('phrase_1', '4'),
>   ('phrase_1', '1'),
>   ('phrase_1', '8'),
>   ('phrase_2', '2'),
>   ('phrase_3', '3'),
>   ('phrase_3', '2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT phrase,total,(total - mi/ma - mi) AS rank
> FROM
>  (SELECT phrase, sum(qty) as total 
> FROM mytable
> GROUP By phrase
> ORDER BY total DESC) t1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(total) mi,MAX(total) ma
> FROM
>  (SELECT phrase, sum(qty) as total 
> FROM mytable
> GROUP By phrase
> ORDER BY total DESC) t1) t2
> ```

> ```
> phrase   | total |    rank
> :------- | ----: | ------:
> phrase_1 |    13 | 10.8462
> phrase_3 |     5 |  2.8462
> phrase_2 |     2 | -0.1538
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3df2d02bb8e5457724d094638d6633f1)*

Answer (score 1):

You want window functions:

```
SELECT phrase, sum(qty) as total,
       MIN(SUM(qty)) OVER () as min_total,
       MAX(SUM(qty)) OVER () as max_total
FROM mytable
GROUP By phrase
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like it's support in MySQL 8+.  Checked version and it won't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below :

```
SELECT phrase, sum(qty) as total,
       MIN(SUM(qty)) OVER () as min_total,
       MAX(SUM(qty)) OVER () as max_total
into #temp
FROM mytable
GROUP By phrase
ORDER BY total DESC

Select *,(total - min_total/max_total - min_total) AS rank From #temp
Drop Table #temp
```